# How to use args of macro as part of function's name? like \foo#1bar -> \fooargbar

Tags: macros

How to call the function using macro arguement `#1` as a part of name of that function?

It is analogue of `#define` in `C++`.

The code will describe you the simple idea:

```
\newsavebox\QAAAX
\newsavebox\QAABX

\savebox\QAAAX{First}
\savebox\QAABX{Second}

\renewcommand{\makak}[1] {
 \Q#1X %???? It does not work.
}

\makak{AAA} % i need to call \QAAAX and get the output: First
\makak{AAB} % i need to call \QAABX and get the output: Second
```

Comment: see `eboxtools` package and its `\csdef` and `\csuse` macros.

Comment: The `\renewcommand` is useless here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\QAAAX
\newsavebox\QAABX

\savebox\QAAAX{First}
\savebox\QAABX{Second}

\newcommand{\makak}[1] {
 \usebox{\csname Q#1X\endcsname}%???? It does not work.
}

\makak{AAA} % i need to call \QAAAX and get the output: First
\makak{AAB} % i need to call \QAABX and get the output: Second
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is the LaTeX3 approach.  Some functions of the new LaTeX3 kernel take a control sequence, such as `\QAAAX` as an argument (denoted by the `:N` in `\some_kernel_function:N`).  Most (if not all) of these functions are overloaded to also take a sequence of tokens which is then converted to a control sequence (for the example above the overload would read `\some_kernel_function:c`).  The two following calls to `\some_kernel_function:...` are hence completely equivalent:

```
\some_kernel_function:N \QAAAX
\some_kernel_function:c { QAAAX }
```

I picked up Steven's MWE and implemented it with the new `l3coffin` module of the LaTeX3 kernel instead of “ordinary” boxes.  If you would like to find out why coffins are much better than boxes I recommend you to read the manual of the [`xcoffins`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3experimental/xcoffins/xcoffins.pdf) package.  `xcoffins` is merely a frontend for the `l3coffin` module, designed for those who are scared of the `expl3` syntax (which I can relate to).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\coffin_new:N \l_dunaev_AAA_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_dunaev_AAB_coffin

\hcoffin_set:Nn \l_dunaev_AAA_coffin {First}
\hcoffin_set:Nn \l_dunaev_AAB_coffin {Second}

\NewDocumentCommand \makak { m }
 {
  \coffin_typeset:cnnnn { l_dunaev_#1_coffin } { l } { T } { 0pt } { 0pt }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\makak{AAA}
\makak{AAB}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

I thought it might be illustrative to have an example using the `xcoffins` package, because of my talking about it above, so here you go.  The output is the same as for the `expl3` example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\NewCoffin\QAAAX
\NewCoffin\QAABX

\SetHorizontalCoffin\QAAAX{First}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\QAABX{Second}

\newcommand\makak[1]{%
  \expandafter\TypesetCoffin\csname Q#1X\endcsname[l,T]%
}

\begin{document}
\makak{AAA}
\makak{AAB}
\end{document}
```

---

## A comment on the C++ claim

In your question you claim, that in C++ you can call a function using a macro parameter with `#define`.  Even though this is true, I *highly discourage* doing so!

Let us consider this super useless example:  We want to have a universal print function which can print the value of any printable type.  Therefore we define

```cpp
#define PRINT(type, value) print_##type(value)
```

If we now call `PRINT(int, i)` this macro will expand to `print_int(i)`.  There we already exprience the first pitfall.  What if `print_int(int value)` is not implemented?  Well, we will get an error message, which can be rectified by implementing the appropriate funtion. Easy!

Unfortunately, this breaks down as soon as we use types whose names include characters which are not qualified to go into a function name, such as `std::string`.  The `::` is illegal in a function name, except to denote its namespace in the very beginning, and even if we swap the order in the macro expansion such that the macro expands to `std::string_print(…)` instead of `print_std::string(…)` we would still get an error (at least by some compilers), because it is–per the standard–not allowed to add things to the `std` namespace.

All of these downside can be overcome by the concept of *templates* in C++.  For our stupid universal printing function a correct template would read

```cpp
template<typename T>
void print(const T& value) {
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

That's it!  You can now instantiate this template with any type that overloads the `operator<<(std::ostream& out, T& value)`.  Otherwise you receive `error: invalid operands to binary expression`.

**Conclusion:** Never use preprocessor macros to mimic function templates!

Here is the full example with some of the edge cases discussed in the previous text.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// ===
// The macro approach
// ===

#define PRINT(type, value) print_##type(value)

void print_int(int value) {
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

void print_double(double value) {
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

/* error! "::" not allow in function name
void print_std::string(std::string value) {
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
*/

// ===
// The template approach
// ===

template<typename T>
void print(const T& value) {
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int i = 2;
  float f = 3.2;
  double d = 5.1;
  std::string s("ABC");

  PRINT(int, i);
  // print_float is not implemented!
  // PRINT(float, f); // <- error: use of undeclared identifier 'print_float'
  PRINT(double, d);
  // PRINT(std::string, s); // <- error: use of undeclared identifier 'print_std' 

  print(i);
  print(f);
  print(d);
  print(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities: `\csname #1\endcsname` to generate the box name or `\csuse{#1}` from the `etoolbox`. For this easy example, the first way is sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newsavebox\QAAAX
\newsavebox\QAABX
\newsavebox\QAACX
\newsavebox\QAADX

\savebox\QAAAX{First}
\savebox\QAABX{Second}
\savebox\QAACX{Third}
\savebox\QAADX{Fourth}

\newcommand{\makak}[1]{%
\usebox{\csname Q#1X\endcsname}% 
}



\newcommand{\makakother}[1]{%
\usebox{\csuse{Q#1X}}% 
}


\begin{document}

\makak{AAA} % i need to call \QAAAX and get the output: First
\makak{AAB} % i need to call \QAABX and get the output: Second

\makakother{AAC} % 
\makakother{AAD} % 


\end{document}
```

[image]